# Renamed the same file using java

Tags: java, file, file-io

I want to renamed file `140103122005+0530_Penguins.jpg` to `Penguins.jpg` from same directory.

I have tried `renameTo()` but it is not working, it requires destination file, I don't have destination file.

Anyone can tell me how to I rename the same file from same directory using Java.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_renameto.htm

Comment: your _destination file_ will be the same as your current file location

Answer (score 6):

Please read the [renameTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) java doc carefully. It requires **abstract destination File** object (which does not necessarily mean the file must exist on your system). It is just a indicator to the renameTo() method about the destination file on your system. [File documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) clearly says that the **file object is abstract representation of the file or directory** (the actual file may or may not exist).

Here is a java code snippet for reference:

```
// This file to be renamed (must exist on your system)
File source = new File("c:/140103122005+0530_Penguins.jpg");

if(source.exists()) {
    // Abstract file path (does not exist)
    File destination = new File ("c:/Penguins.jpg");

    // rename the source file
    source.renameTo(destination);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example

```
import java.io.*;
public class file {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File f=new File("140103122005+0530_Penguins.jpg");
        f.renameTo(new File("Penguins.jpg"));

    }

}
```

`remaneTo` returns `boolean` so if you want to check whther file has been renamed or not then do `System.out.println(f.renameTo(new File("Penguins.jpg"));` If you get true then file renamed

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are doing something wrong. It's supposed to be

```
boolean success = new File("1").renameTo(new File("2"));
```

Note that according to javadoc it might not be able to move a file from one filesystem to another, and it might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname already exists. renameTo is platform-dependent.

Since Java 7 it is recommended to use platform-independent `java.nio.file.Files.move` method instead

Answer (score 0):

Also check whether renaming has succeeded or not by the return paramater of the **File.renameTo** method. File renaming operation is platform-dependent and may not succeed all the time.